# optimize function python dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have this python code of the supertrend implementation. i am using pandas dataframe. the code works fine but, the supertrend function runs slower and slower as the dataframe increases in length. I was wondering if there is anything I could change in the code to optimize it and make it go faster even with a large dataframe length.

```
def trueRange(df):
    df['prevClose'] = df['close'].shift(1)
    df['high-low'] = df['high'] - df['low']
    df['high-pClose'] = abs(df['high'] - df['prevClose'])
    df['low-pClose'] = abs(df['low'] - df['prevClose'])
    tr = df[['high-low','high-pClose','low-pClose']].max(axis=1)
    
    return tr

def averageTrueRange(df, peroid=12):
    df['trueRange'] = trueRange(df)
    the_atr = df['trueRange'].rolling(peroid).mean()
    
    return the_atr
    

def superTrend(df, peroid=5, multipler=1.5):
    df['averageTrueRange'] = averageTrueRange(df, peroid=peroid)
    h2 = ((df['high'] + df['low']) / 2)
    df['Upperband'] = h2 + (multipler * df['averageTrueRange'])
    df['Lowerband'] = h2 - (multipler * df['averageTrueRange'])
    df['inUptrend'] = None

    for current in range(1,len(df.index)):
        prev = current- 1
        
        if df['close'][current] > df['Upperband'][prev]:
            df['inUptrend'][current] = True
            
        elif df['close'][current] < df['Lowerband'][prev]:
            df['inUptrend'][current] = False
        else:
            df['inUptrend'][current] = df['inUptrend'][prev]
            
            if df['inUptrend'][current] and df['Lowerband'][current] < df['Lowerband'][prev]:
                df['Lowerband'][current] = df['Lowerband'][prev]
                
            if not df['inUptrend'][current] and df['Upperband'][current] > df['Upperband'][prev]:
                df['Upperband'][current] = df['Upperband'][prev]
```

vector version

```
def superTrend(df, peroid=5, multipler=1.5):
    df['averageTrueRange'] = averageTrueRange(df, peroid=peroid)
    h2 = ((df['high'] + df['low']) / 2)
    df['Upperband'] = h2 + (multipler * df['averageTrueRange'])
    df['Lowerband'] = h2 - (multipler * df['averageTrueRange'])
    df['inUptrend'] = None


    cond1 = df['close'].values[1:] > df['Upperband'].values[:-1]
    cond2 = df['close'].values[1:] < df['Lowerband'].values[:-1]

    df.loc[cond1, 'inUptrend'] = True
    df.loc[cond2, 'inUptrend'] = False

    df.loc[(~cond1) & (cond2), 'inUptrend'] = df['inUptrend'][:-1]
    df.loc[(~cond1) & (cond2) & (df['inUptrend'].values[1:] == True) & (df['Lowerband'].values[1:] < df['Lowerband'].values[:-1]), 'Lowerband'] = df['Lowerband'][:-1]
    df.loc[(~cond1) & (cond2) & (df['inUptrend'].values[1:] == False) & (df['Upperband'].values[1:] > df['Upperband'].values[:-1]), 'Upperband'] = df['Upperband'][:-1]
```

[image: example of data]

Comment: A loop like `for current in range(1,len(df.index)):` is almost always going to be slow with larger DataFrames. Numba in "nopython" mode can sometimes be used to speed up loops like this. https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/user/5minguide.html#what-is-nopython-mode Otherwise, try to find a "vectorized" version of what you are trying to do to avoid a loop.

Comment: i got this error TypingError: cannot determine Numba type of <class 'function'> when i tired using jit(nopython=True)

Comment: Numba only supports a subset of Python when `nopython=True`. You'll need to structure your code in a way that can be jitted if you want to optimize in that way.

Comment: i have edited the question witha vectorized version but it is not printing the same as the loop version can you help me please

Comment: Can you please give/point to some sample data to test it.

Comment: Have you profiled what parts of your code are taking the most time?  e.g. if it turns out that `trueRange` is costly, then it is likely because `max(axis=1)`  is inefficient (though we're improving that in an upcoming version!)

Comment: yes a simple optimización to avoid the loop is to use apply

Answer (score 8):

Instead of `import pandas as pd`, try using [Modin](https://modin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). Modin automatically makes pandas much faster. Just do `import modin.pandas as pd`. You don't need to change any code other than the import.

If you need to use the `df.apply()` method, there is a package called [Swifter](https://github.com/jmcarpenter2/swifter). After you `pip install swifter`, all you need to do is `import swifter`, and then instead of doing `df.apply()`, do `df.swifter.apply()`. What's convenient is that Swifter also works with Modin.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the Numba / Numpy version of your code. You have to convert your df[ 'close' ], df[ 'high' ] and df[ 'low' ] as numpy arrays for speed benefit. I didn't check if the output values are correct but you got the idea.

```
import numpy as np
from numba import jit

# UNCOMMENT THIS LINE IF YOU DON'T HAVE THE OPEN PRICES
# c_open = np.concatenate((np.array([np.nan]), c_close[1:]))

@jit(nopython=True)
def true_range(c_open, c_high, c_low):
    return np.maximum(np.maximum(c_high - c_low, np.abs(c_high - c_open)), np.abs(c_low - c_open))


@jit(nopython=True)
def average_true_range(c_open, c_high, c_low, period=12):
    true_r = true_range(c_open, c_high, c_low)
    size = len(true_r)
    out = np.array([np.nan] * size)
    for i in range(period - 1, size):
        window = true_r[i - period + 1:i + 1]
        out[i] = np.mean(window)
    return out


@jit(nopython=True)
def super_trend(c_close, c_open, c_high, c_low, period=5, multipler=1.5):
    size = len(c_close)
    avg_true_r = average_true_range(c_open, c_high, c_low, period=period)
    h2 = (c_high + c_low) / 2
    upper_band = h2 + (multipler * avg_true_r)
    lower_band = h2 - (multipler * avg_true_r)
    in_up_trend = np.array([np.nan] * size)
    for current in range(1, size):
        prev = current - 1
        if c_close[current] > upper_band[prev]:
            in_up_trend[current] = True
        elif c_close[current] < lower_band[prev]:
            in_up_trend[current] = False
        else:
            in_up_trend[current] = in_up_trend[prev]
            if in_up_trend[current] and lower_band[current] < lower_band[prev]:
                lower_band[current] = lower_band[prev]
            if not in_up_trend[current] and upper_band[current] > upper_band[prev]:
                upper_band[current] = upper_band[prev]
    return upper_band, lower_band, in_up_trend
```

Edit : If you don't use Heiken Ashi, you don't need to shift the close prices to get the last close prices as they are equivalent to open prices ;)

Feel free to check my [lib of fast indicators @ github](https://github.com/RomFR57/fastfinance)